# Pass type parameter with exact constraint to function with that argument?

Tags: go, generics

I am starting to use Go generics and have a hard time to understand why this code will not compile:

```golang
func f(string) {}

func xyz[T string](p T) {
    f(p) // Error! Cannot use 'p' (type T) as the type string
}
```

In function `xyz`, why can it not be assumed that there is a type constraint on T such that T is the string type?

I understand that I could simply write `f(string(p))`, but I am still interested in the answer to the question.

Comment: You can also change the declaration of `f` to `func f[T string](T) {}`. A type constraint with a single type X is simply not the same as the single type `X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the rules of [assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability), in your specific case it's the last rule.

> V is a type parameter and T is **not a named type**, and values of each type in V's type set are assignable to T.

Type `string` is a **named type** and because of that, even though each type in `T`'s type set is assignable to `string`, the type parameter `T` itself is not assignable to `string`.

You can compare this with an **unnamed type**.

```golang
func f([]string) {}

func xyz[T []string](p T) {
    f(p) // no issue
}
```